# Execute SP as many times as rows in a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my SP I have TVP type which include product information like,

```
Name Desc Visible Tags
```

This TVP include n rows. I am inserting this n rows in my Products table and putting the inserted Ids with Tags column in a temp table. After inserting, I need to execute my SP for each of the inserted product,

```
EXEC [InsertOrUpdateTags]
```

Means I need to execute this SP as many times as the number of rows in the temp table and passing the inserted Id. How can I do this? Here is my SP

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrUpdateTags] 
            (
                @ProductId INT
                 ,@Tags NVARCHAR(225)
            )
            AS
            BEGIN

                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                DECLARE @TranCount INT;
                SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

                BEGIN TRY
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                    ELSE
                        SAVE TRANSACTION InsertOrUpdateTags;


                    DECLARE @Tag TABLE(Name NVARCHAR(50));

                    DECLARE @TagIds TABLE(Id INT)

                    INSERT INTO @Tag
                    SELECT Items FROM dbo.Split(@Tags,',');

                    MERGE Tags AS D
                    USING (SELECT Name FROM @Tag) S 
                        ON D.Name = S.Name
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT(Name)
                        VALUES(S.Name)
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE
                            SET Name = S.Name
                    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @TagIds;

                    -- Delete the one which was available before but not now
                    DELETE FROM ProductsTags WHERE BaseProductId = @ProductId AND TagId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @TagIds);

                    MERGE ProductsTags AS D
                    USING (SELECT Id FROM @TagIds) S 
                        ON D.TagId = S.Id AND D.BaseProductId = @ProductId
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT(BaseProductId, TagId)
                        VALUES(@ProductId, S.Id);


 LBEXIT:
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        COMMIT;
                    END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
                    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

                    IF @XState = -1
                        ROLLBACK;
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
                        rollback
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  InsertOrUpdateTags;

                    RAISERROR (' InsertOrUpdateTags: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
                END CATCH
            END
```

Comment: I think you want a `while` loop:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you mean cursor

Comment: Why not use triggers?

Comment: @Ric, can you give me an example?

Comment: What does `InsertTags` do? what you are suggesting is not what sql server is good at. it may be possible to do this in a set based way rather than row by row

Comment: @ughai, The problem is that we have check first a tag exist or not then we will insert this tag in Tags table. Then we have insert/update/delete ProductTags table.

Comment: Looks like what you are explaining can be easily accomplished by joins with your temp table. if you can add your existing code in `InsertTags` and your `TVP` structure, someone can help you create a set based solution.

Comment: Have you looked at a `MERGE` statement?  You can do the insert/update/delete all at once while checking for existence of a tag.

Comment: why not change procedure to process a set instead of one row at the time? You can use user defined table type to pass a list of values to the procedure and process everything at once.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky example will be apprecited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `CROSS APPLY` with your `Split` to get all list of products with tag in a table variable and use the table variable in all your merge statements.
Something like this.

```
    DECLARE @TempProduct TABLE(ProductID INTTagName VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @TempProduct(ProductID,TagName)
    SELECT ProductID,S.Items
    FROM #TempTable CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Tags,',') S;

    MERGE Tags AS D
    USING (SELECT DISTINCT TagName FROM @TempProduct) S 
        ON D.Name = S.Name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(Name)
        VALUES(S.Name)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
            SET Name = S.Name
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID,Inserted.Name INTO @TagIds(ID,Name);

    -- Delete the one which was available before but not now
    DELETE FROM ProductsTags
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TempProduct TP INNER JOIN @TagIds TS ON TP.TagName = TS.TagName WHERE TP.ProductID = BaseProductId AND TS.ID= ProductsTags.TagId);

    MERGE ProductsTags AS D
    USING (SELECT TP.ProductID,TS.ID FROM @TempProduct TP INNER JOIN @TagIds TS ON TP.TagName = TS.TagName) S 
        ON D.TagId = S.ID AND D.BaseProductId = ProductID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(BaseProductId, TagId)
        VALUES(ProductID, TagID);


LBEXIT:
    IF @TranCount = 0
        COMMIT;
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

    IF @XState = -1
        ROLLBACK;
    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
        rollback
    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  InsertOrUpdateTags;

    RAISERROR (' InsertOrUpdateTags: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
END CATCH
END
```

***Note:** this was written here directly and might have some issues.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But will review

Comment: `    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TempProduct TP WHERE TP.ProductID = BaseProductId AND TP.TagId = TP.TagId);
` This line has something wrong

Comment: But TempProduct does not include TagId

Comment: I think we need inner join